# SSRS 2014 Data Driven SubScriptions not available

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2014, subscriptions

I am currently looking into Setting up Data Driven Subscriptions on our 2014 Server, however when trying to follow the instructions in the tutorials I can find I'm running into a roadblock, which is as simple as I just don't see the option for Data Driven Subscriptions anywhere! Is there a service or some setting that I am missing ? I have complete Admin access to the server & the Reporting Server site.

Thanks

Comment: ... where are you expecting to see the option for Data Driven Subscriptions?

Comment: What edition of SQL Server are you using? I believe that Data Driven Subscriptions are an Enterprise Edition feature.

Answer (score 0):

Data Driven subscriptions are only available on Enterprise and Business Intelligence editions of SQL Server 2014:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.120).aspx#Reporting

I have often run into this limitation, and it has kept me from developing data-drvien subscriptions many times. The cost difference to upgrade to SQL Enterprise usually kills the value of this feature. One easy work around is to have the subscription run regularly, but change the data in the report depending on the recipient.